# gsp changes not reflecting in grails 2.5.1

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, bootstrap-modal, asset-pipeline

I am trying to show a modal on a particular condition in javascript using grails template.But my changes are not visible . Here is the java scripts code :

```
if(!isSame){
                alert("Hiii");
                $('#edit-state-modal2').modal('show')
            }
```

The alert comes but the modal does not open. The gsp code is as follows :

```
<g:render template="/includes/widgets/edit_state_errmsg_modal" />
```

In the template edit_state_errmsg_modal :

```
<div class="modal fade " id="edit-state-modal2"  role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using grails version 2.5.1. In the developer console I am unable to see the gsp(html) code. It looks like some grails related problem. I have restarted the app(using run-app) and build the war(using run-war) and deployed too.But nothing helps. Please help me out. Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

what i can see - the following line in javascript not ended with `;`

```
$('#edit-state-modal2').modal('show')
```

but in general use your browser development tools (`F12` button)

and in console you should see all javascript and not only problems on your page.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake. I was putting the gsp code in wrong gsp. Sorry for troubling all.

Comment: I highly recommend you delete your question as it was a simple typo issue and as a question/answer it serves little to no value for future readers.

Comment: When i try to delete the question it says:
You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering